# Elixir Absinthe GraphQL, Union resolve_type list_of/1

Tags: graphql, elixir, absinthe

I need help. I'm looking for a way to resolve a list_of(:object) in union.
Here's what I did.

```
object :community_queries do
  field :search, type: :search_result do
    arg(:keyword, non_null(:string))

    resolve(&CommunityResolver.search/3)
  end
end
```

...

```
union :search_result do
  description "A search result"

  types [:person, :business]
  resolve_type fn
    %Person{}, _ -> list_of(:person)
    %Business{}, _ -> list_of(:business)
  end
end
```

In the code above. I tried to put a list_of(:person) in resolve_type and it returns error like this

```
invalid quoted expression: %Absinthe.Blueprint.TypeReference.List{errors: [], of_type: :person}
```

Then I tried this one

```
object :community_queries do
  field :search, type: list_of(:search_result) do
    arg(:keyword, non_null(:string))

    resolve(&CommunityResolver.search/3)
  end
end
```

...

```
union :search_result do
  description "A search result"

  types [:person, :business]
  resolve_type fn
    %Person{}, _ -> :person
    %Business{}, _ -> :business
  end
end
```

It returns

```
 (BadMapError) expected a map, got: [%{name: "John"}, ...
```

I've also tried putting it in types like this but also got errors.

```
...
types [list_of(:person), list_of(:business)]
  resolve_type fn
...
```

Is there a possible workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
object :community_queries,  do
  field :search, type: list_of(:search_result) do
    arg(:keyword, non_null(:string))

    resolve(&CommunityResolver.search/3)
  end
end
```

`:community_queries` is a query argument and should be defined as a field instead of an object which looks up either a person or business, lets call them `users`. This defined field looks like it returns `:search_result`.

```
field :community_queries, :search_result do
  arg(:keyword, non_null(:string))

  resolve(&CommunityResolver.search/3)
end
```

You'll need to define what the `search_result` object looks like, which sounds like it's a list of `users`.

More about query arguments [here](https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/query-arguments.html)